# R how to remove repeated value while save unique values in running length

Tags: r, vector, repeat

So Example I have this vectors:

```
v <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

And I like to Simplify the vectors as this expected outputs:

```
exp_output <- c(3,1,3,2,3)
```

Whats the best and convenient way to do this? Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `rle(v)$values` which results in `[1] 3 1 3 2 3`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `diff` and `which`.

```
v[c(1, which(diff(v) != 0) + 1)]
#[1] 3 1 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is with `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)
v[v!=lag(v, default=1)]
```

```
[1] 3 1 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
tapply(v, rleid(v), FUN = first)
1 2 3 4 5 
3 1 3 2 3
```